# Sublime text: Replace every nth occurrence of comma using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a file with hundreds of line like quoted below. I want to change the indexed array to an associative array by adding keys.

`(['Maricao', 'PR', '00606', '18.182778', '-66.980278']),`

so after the process, what I need is

`(['name' =>'Maricao', 'code' => 'PR', 'zip' => '00606', 'lat' => '18.182778', ' lng' =>'-66.980278']),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the keys and order are the same. Find:

```
('[^']+', )('[^']+', )('[^']+', )('[^']+', )('[^']+')
```

Replace with:

```
'name' => \1'code' => \2'zip' => \3'lat' => \4'lng' => \5
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)